# How to select textbox2 from textbox1?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, focus

I have 2 textboxes. 
How do i do: When i click textbox1 the mouse goes to textbox2 so i can write in textbox2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `Focus()` it:

```
private void textbox1_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    textbox2.Focus();
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't worked, i had an error. Thx anyway because now i know that i was doing it right and i had an error. I tried to focus textblock and it didn't work.

Comment: A textblock can't be focused (or edited for that matter). If you make it a textbox you should be good to go.

Comment: Exactly. `TextBlock` *isn't editable*. You can't focus a non editable control. You called it as `textbox2`, so you must use a `TextBox`.